# Pivot a table in HiveSQL - not a key/value pair situation

Tags: pivot, hiveql

I need to pivot a long table using Hive SQL.  The table looks like this:
[image]

and I want it to look like this:

[image]

where N is some user-defined cutoff.  I found examples of how to do this when the original table contains columns of id, keys, and values, but nothing where it's just id's and values and there's no fixed number of those values for a given id.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need dynamic sql. Once you know the cut off, you can write the sql, so python to write sql or something like that.  But there is no pure/native sql (or HiveQL) way to return a data set with a run-time defined number of columns.